# If not let - in Swift

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

is there is a way to negate the "if let" in swift? 
This looks silly to me:

```
    if let type = json.type  {

    } else {
        XCTFail("There is no type in the root element")
    }
```

I can't use XCTAssertNotNil, because json.type is a enum.

```
enum JSONDataTypes {
    case Object
    case Array
    case Number
    case String
}
```

Thanks a lot

EDIT: it is a:

```
var type: JSONDataTypes? = nil
```

Comment: Is `json.type` a bare `JSONDataTypes`, or is it a `JSONDataTypes?` (optional)?

Comment: oh sorry: 
var type: JSONDataTypes? = nil

Comment: This is indeed the thing that most often frustrates me about Swift

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7) and later have the new `guard` statement, which sort of works like an "if not let" -- you can conditionally bind a variable in the remainder of the enclosing scope, keeping the "good path" in your code the least-indented.

```
guard let type = json.type else {
    XCTFail("There is no type in the root element")
}
// do something with `type` here
```

The catch to this is that the `else` clause of a `guard` must exit that scope (because otherwise you'd fall into code after that clause, where the guarded variables, like `type` above, are unbound). So it has to end with something like `return`, `break`, `continue` or a function that is known to the compiler to never return (i.e. annotated `@noreturn`, like `abort()`... I don't recall offhand if that includes `XCTFail`, but it should ([file a bug if it's not](http://bugreport.apple.com)).

For details, see [Early Exit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID525) in *The Swift Programming Language*.

---

As for really-old stuff... There's no negated form of if-let in Swift 1.x. But since you're working with XCTest anyway, you can just make testing the optional part of an assertion expression:

```
XCTAssert(json.type != nil, "There is no type in the root element")
```

Comment: There's literally no "if not let" in Swift 2, but the new `guard` statement is pretty much what you're looking for. Updated answer.

Comment: `guard let else {}` is not the equivalent of `if not let {}` since in the scope of `guard` must always call `return` or `break`. They can not be allowed to fall through: `'guard' body may not fall through, consider using 'return' or 'break' to exit the scope`

Answer (score 24):

Here's how you do it:

```
if json.type == nil {
  // fail
}
```

Comment: That doesn't assign json.type to type though

Comment: Of course, because `type` is not an optional and therefore cannot hold a nil value. Your answer doesn't assign anything to type either. It's impossible.

Comment: @ChoppinBroccoli The original question implies that Peter Shaw doesn't care about the actual type.  He's writing a test case that fails if `json.type` is nil and he wants to do it more succinctly.

Comment: @rob I don't understand how you can claim he doesn't care about the 'type' variable?  He is assigning it and may want to use it after.  I think it's important for this question because it doesn't seem to work by negating if let with an exclamation mark.

Comment: He didn't put anything (like `...` or `// code here`) in the consequent of the `if` statement. Also, he wanted to ‘negate the "if let"’. Together these imply that he didn't care about the value.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative I've used a few times:

```
switch json.type
{
    case .None: // ...
    case .Some(.Object): // ...
    case .Some(.Array):  // ...
    case .Some(.Number): // ...
    case .Some(.String): // ...
}
```

Since the `?` is actually `Optional<T>` which is an enum on its own, defined as:

```
enum Optional<T> : Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible 
{
    case None
    case Some(T)

    ...
}
```