# Storing a Boolean for access by Parse login

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, boolean, ivar

I want to store a Boolean which grants access to certain options when a user logs in with Parse, but when I log in and declare it to be true, the variable seems to remain false.

I tried using NSUserDefaults and storing a global variable.

This is where I log in on one view controller:

```
 PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(userName.text!, password: password.text!) {
            (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if user != nil {


               NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "accessGranted")



            }
```

This functions fine and prints "Success" if I try. 
On another view controller I have things like this:

```
addButton.enabled = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("accessGranted")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NSUserDefaults:**

Your are missing key component for it to work - you have to save the settings:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "accessGranted")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

After that, your data that you stored will be stored to disk and you can access them anytime.

**One-time assign to property:**

After reading through comment, in order to access property only once, you can use something like this:

```
var accessGranted : Bool?
if accessGranted == nil {
    accessGranted = yourValue
}
```

or as of Swift 2.0 ([more on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412735/if-not-let-in-swift)):

```
var accessGranted : Bool?
guard let granted = accessGranted else {
    accessGranted = yourValue
}
```

Edit 2:

To notify second VC about changes, you can use multiple mechanisms (protocols / delegates etc.), but usually for this kind of message you would use Notifications (so your whole application can listen to that).

**Notifications**

You can use notifications like this:

In your "login" call, notify application that your access status changed, like this:

```
let NOTIFICATION_ACCESS_CHANGED_KEY = "NotificationAccessChanged"
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(NOTIFICATION_ACCESS_CHANGED)
```

then, everywhere where you are interested to listen to that change, put notification listener:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NOTIFICATION_ACCESS_CHANGED, object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) -> Void in

    // This block will be called when you post notification
    self.doSomething()
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have found the problem: as I am using a master detail view controller the app does not reload the master page when I run and therefore prevents access: any ideas?

Comment: Try using notifications :) NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter.postNotificationName && NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName

Comment: Sounds good but could you please post an answer with more detail, then I can accept it as well ;)

Comment: I added more elaborate answer :)

Comment: Thanks that was helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` to store your `Bool` globally this way:

Set your `Bool` this way:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "YourKey")
```

Then you can access it anywhere in your project this way:

```
let yourBool = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("YourKey")
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: That was a great solution based on my post however I was wrong about the problem. I tried this out and it didn't work. What should I try now?

Comment: Check it out... @DharmeshKheni

Comment: Did you check that your bool is setting true with this code? I mean it is entering in this if condition?

Comment: Yes, I received true (it works): I printed NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("YourKey") right after the change succesfully

Comment: Are you getting false when you read it's values at button code?

Comment: Damn I found the problem, what a foolish mistake: I set the value to be false in the viewDidLoad so this is called EVERY time the view loads. Is there anything I can do to set it only the first time?

Comment: I guess I could use Bool for key in NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: It will set to false by default when you declare it

Comment: I have found another problem: as I am using a master detail view controller the app does not reload the master page when I run and therefore prevents access: any ideas?

Comment: Feel free to ask another question with more detail..:)