# Only else-block of "if let"?

Tags: swift, if-statement, let

In a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have:

```
if let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(SOME_TAG) as? UIImageView
{
    // Nothing to do here.
}
else
{
    // Add image view to cell.
}
```

but I only need the `else` block. Is there a way to invert a `if let xyz =`?

(I know I could break it up and have a `if imageView == nil`.)

Just found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412735/if-not-let-in-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27412931/1208191

Comment: Another good recommendation would be to avoid tags as much as possible. They really pollute source code.

Comment: @Sulthan Agreed, but adds the least pollution for finding back added subview to reusable table view cells.

Comment: @meaning-matters Nope. Custom cells that hold added subviews as properties are much easier to maintain but that would be a lengthy discussion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
if cell.viewWithTag(SOME_TAG) == nil {

}
```

Comment: This does not get the job done if cell.viewWithTag(SOME_TAG) is a different UIView that is not an UIImageView. The question is looking for cases where converting cell.viewWithTag fails to cast to UIImageView

Answer (score 7):

You can use guard. It does exactly what you need:

```
guard let x = x where x > 0 else {
        // Value requirements not met, do something
        return
    }
```

Comment: Nice, but it does not feel like a `guard` situation to me. But perhaps I just need to get used to its use in situations like this.

Comment: @meaning-matters `guard let _ = cell.viewWithTag(SOME_TAG) else { return }`.

Comment: This is simply the inverse logic of what as asked, or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't know why this answer was accepted. The other two answers are what is being asked for.

Comment: @rmaddy OP dont want to use if imageView == nil. Guard is the opposite of "if let". That is what he asked, as far as I know

Comment: @Juan Curti The OP wants to do something special in the `else` case - i.e. adding an image view - and for this `guard` is semantically not suited. Guard is not the opposite of `if`..., it has a very dedicated semantic - typically at function entry - to ensure correct values and to provide a quick exit. Although it _might_ work, it is no common use to use it that way.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Sure, you're right. And that definition is excellent. I would simply use a if (.. == nil) as everyone else said

Comment: @AndreasOetjen As seen in first comment, I agree.

Comment: The problem with guard is its else-block specifically requires user to exit whatever function continues the guard statement. So if OP wants an else-check in the middle of a function, then continue with some unrelated code, they won't be able to with guard.

Answer (score 2):

> ... but I only need the else block. Is there a way to invert a `if let xyz =`?

You want to know if you can invert the logic of an *optional binding clause*, to be entered only if the optional binding fails. However, this occurs exactly when the optional expression to bounded (in your case, `cell.viewWithTag(SOME_TAG) as? UIImageView`) is `nil`. Hence, for this kind of logic, there is no reason to attempt to bind the value in the first place; you simply check if the optional expression is `nil`.

The straightforward way of doing this is already covered in two other answers, but as an alternative, you may perform pattern matching for `.none`.

```
if case .none = xyz {
    // implement logic ...
}
```

Or, applied to your example

```
if case .none = cell.viewWithTag(SOME_TAG) as? UIImageView {
    // implement logic ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
if cell.viewWithTag(SOME_TAG) == nil {
    // Add image 
}
```